# Using Bitwise Operators to get Bit Values in C

Tags: c, bitwise-operators

I am writing a program in C where I am comparing two bytes of data, and then seeing if the bytes are different, and if so, at which bits.

This is what I have so far:

```
int var1 = 81;  //Binary: 0101 0001
int var2 = 193; //Binary: 1100 0001
int diff = var1 ^ var2; //diff = 1001 0000 / 144
```

Basically I know how to use the XOR bitwise operator to see which bits are different between the two variables, but from here I don't know how to use diff to figure out which bits are the differences.  For example, in my above code I'd want to use diff to output "Bit 5 and Bit 8 are different".

Comment: They're (usually) not bits 5 and 8, but [**4** and **7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Far easier to **start** with `unsigned` types when doing bit manipulations.

---

As [@coderredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853952/using-bitwise-operators-to-get-bit-values-in-c/48853999?noredirect=1#comment84711676_48853999) inquired about solutions across various platforms, even uncommon ones:

Using `int`:

When `int diff` is negative, conversion to an `unsigned` (via masking with an `unsigned`) may [change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48853952/using-bitwise-operators-to-get-bit-values-in-c/48853999?noredirect=1#comment84711982_48853999) its bit pattern.

An `int` may have more than 8 bits per "byte".  Diminishes correctness of `sizeof(int)*8`.

Various integer types may have padding (rare). Diminishes  correctness of `sizeof(int)*CHAR_BIT`.

```
// OP wants to report first bit index as 1.  0 is more common.
#define BIT_REPORT_OFFSET 0

int bit_position = 0;
int mask;
do {
  mask = 1 << bit_position;
  if (diff & mask) {
    printf("Bit %d\n", bit_position + BIT_REPORT_OFFSET);
  }
  bit_position++;
} while (mask < INT_MAX/2);

if (diff < 0) {
  printf("Bit %d\n", bit_position + BIT_REPORT_OFFSET);
}
```

---

For maximum portability, avoid changing types, changing the value of `diff` and use constants from `<limits.h>` rather than compute them.

Comment: Thank you very much for the well thought out answer.  I learned a lot in that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a for `loop` to get that idea and make bitwise `AND` with `1` properly left shifted to get the set bits positions

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(int)*8; i++){
  if( diff & (1U << i))
    printf("%zu is different\n",i+1);
}
```

Comment: damn, you beat me, I discarded my answer as it was the same :)

Comment: What is the `1U` inside the if statement? I haven't seen that before.

Comment: @Skitzafreak it means that the 1 should be consider as an `unsigned int`.

Comment: @chux.: Is it wise to use `CHAR_BIT`..almost all architectures today have CHAR_BIT as `8`

Comment: That is a style issue.  Style issues are best determined by your group/company style guide as it is more important to follow that than spend much effort doing what is "best".

Comment: @chux.: Technically `CHAR_BIT>=8` that's why first wrote `CHAR_BIT` and then it stung me ...and rolled back.

Comment: `CHAR_BIT` self documents codes intent and of course works better with non-8 platforms.  Yet if we look at non-8,  non-2's complement, or padded `int`, `diff & (1U << i)` fails in other ways.  OP's starting premise of using `int` rather than `unsigned` makes for   unnecessary issues.  Coding a solution that is highly portable using `int` is tricky.

Comment: @chux.: Ah that's true. That's also a thing - if you have some time can you elaborate how? I mean I would like to make it clear how in some machines can everything go awry!

Comment: For negative `diff`, `diff & (1U << i)` converts `int diff` to an `unsigned` via  adding `UINT_MAX+1`.  [ref](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Signed_number_representations#Comparison_table)  For _Ones' complement_ and _Sign and magnitude_ (on some ancient/novel platform) this becomes a new bit pattern defeating the coding goal.  Of course with a padded signed integer type `sizeof(type)*8` is a miss.  Easier to assume, like this answer, the [usual suspects](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXuBnz6vtuI).  Better to _start_ with `unsigned` for bit math.

Comment: @chux.I guess I get the points - just that usual suspect I dont understand.(or maybe I do)

Comment: @chux.: Thanks for the comment and the help. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

To get the `different bits` position, lets say you have `4 byte` integer

```
for(int bit_index  = sizeof(diff) - 1; bit_index >= 0;bit_index-- ) {
 if((diff >> bit_index & 1) == 1 ){ /* if particular bit is 1, that bit_index value you can use */ 
  printf("[%d] bit is different or 1 \n",bit_index);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use `unsigned int` instead of `int`; then you can use

```
for (unsigned int pos = 0; diff; ++pos) {
     if (diff & 1)
         printf("difference in pos %u\n", pos);
     diff >>= 1;
}
```

or

```
while (diff) {
    int pos = ffs(diff);
    printf("difference in pos %d\n", pos);

    diff &= ~(1u << pos);
}
```